# Using Webpack with jQuery and Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, webpack

I feel like there should be a straight-up example of this somewhere online. Unfortunately, I've been unsuccessful in finding one. In short, I'm importing Bootstrap 4 via Yarn. One of the dependencies of Bootstrap 4 is jQuery. These two dependencies will be used on all pages in my app. For that reason, I wanted to bundle them together via Webpack. Currently, I have the following:

**app.js**

```
// Import jQuery
const $ = require('jquery');

// Import Bootstrap
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

Then, in my webpack.config.js file, I have the following:

**webpack.config.js**

```
"use strict";

const path = require('path');

const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: './src/js/app.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({$: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({ name: 'common' }),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ],
    output: {
        publicPath: "/js/",
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist/js/'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015']
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
        ]
    },
}
```

However, when I visit a webpack in my page, I see the following error:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined*

How do I bundle jQuery and Bootstrap in my app via Webpack?

Comment: I'm not sure about Webpack, but where on your page are you including jQuery? It must be included before the first instance is called (as in, higher up on the page), or it will throw this error.

Comment: You don't have to require jQuery at all once you've set it as a plugin in your webpack config.

Comment: I'm referencing the bundle in the `head` element of the page. I'm then referencing jQuery at the very end.

Answer (score 0):

As @rick-van-osta pointed out: you don't need to require jquery since you already loaded it via the provide plugin (this will create the global variable **$**):

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({$: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }),
```

remove the line `const $ = require('jquery');` from your app.js and you should be good to go.

there is a **webpack entry** in the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/) btw

also since you are using node_modules, you should be able to change your app.js to:

```
require('bootstrap');
```

Comment: I've used the ProvidePlugin exactly as you said and continue to get "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined." jQuery is in node_modules.

Any suggestions on what to try next?

Comment: what version of webpack are you using? (this answer is months old - javascript has be rewritten several time since then ;)

Comment: Webpack 4. I hadn't considered that. Sorry about that.

Comment: Even after tuning a bit the code from the OP and your answer, I cannot make this work with Webpack 4.41 and Bootstrap 4.4. Could you update your answer with a configuration that works with recent versions?